# How to use TSplitter component in a TPageControl?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Check the image below!

How can I put a TSplitter between two TGroupBox that are inside a TPageControl?

I also tried wrapper the TGroupBoxes in TPanels and put the TSplitter between they, but without success.

The GroupBox02 (and GroupBox 03) also need have the minimum height, to display the datagrid inside it.

Some help?

[image: mockup window]

Comment: I would put both group boxes on a (borderless) panel, set to the upper one `Align` to `alTop`, to the bottom one `alClient` and between them I would drop a splitter with `Align` set to `alTop`.

Comment: Thank you! works fine.
How can I put a margin for the TSplitter. I tried the margins top and bottom attributes for it, but not working.

Comment: Didn't you forget to enable the `AlignWithMargins` property ?

Answer (score 1):

1. put **Panel** on the page controll and change *Align* property of this Panel to **alTop**
2. put **Splitter** on this page, **NOT ON THE PANEL**, and change *Align* property of this Splitter to **alTop**
3. put anothe **Panel** on this page change *Align* property of this panel to **alClient**
   then put **GroupBox1** and **GroupBox2** on the **Panel1** and **GroupBox3** on the **Panel2**

Splitter is used between 2 objects that the align of the one of them must be **alClient**. Splitter changes size and position of this object. The align of the other one must be one of these [**alLeft**, **alTop**, **alRight**, **alBotom**].